# Setting up uv's for ConvexGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

need some help setting up UV's for THREE.js geometry. I made myself a sphere shape out of custom places points in 3D space. I know its easier to just use SphereGeometry and be done with it but I want to learn how to use custom geometry. I currently manage to apply the texture, and it sort of looks good until I noticed this line of texture:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofhcH.png)

At first I thought there was a mistake when generating points for geometry, but after some tweaking I cut down the problem to my UV assignment function:

```js
function assignUVs(geometry, r) {
    function cartesian2polar(position){
        return({
          phi:Math.acos(position.y / r),
          theta:Math.atan2(position.z, position.x)
        });
    }

    function polar2canvas(polarPoint) {
      return({
        y: polarPoint.phi/Math.PI,
        x: (polarPoint.theta+Math.PI) / (2*Math.PI)
      })
    }
        
    var polarVertices = geometry.vertices.map(cartesian2polar);
      
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

    geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {
        var uvs = [];
        var ids = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'];
                
        for( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {
            var vertexIndex = face[ ids[ i ] ];
            var vertex = polarVertices[ vertexIndex ];

            if(vertex.theta === 0 && (vertex.phi === 0 || vertex.phi === Math.PI)) {
                var alignedVertice = vertex.phi === 0 ? face.b : face.a;
                vertex = {
                    phi: vertex.phi,
                    theta: polarVertices[ alignedVertice ].theta
                };
            }
                
            if(vertex.theta === Math.PI && cartesian2polar(face.normal).theta < Math.PI/2) {
                vertex.theta = -Math.PI;
            }

            var canvasPoint = polar2canvas(vertex);

            uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( 1.0-canvasPoint.x, 1.0-canvasPoint.y ) );
            

                geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( uvs );
    });
    
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

So my question is, how to I get rid of this strip of texture?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you may need a tighter UV seam. Your texture looks like `uv.x` winds up to `1.0`, then interpolates back down to `0.0` across that face. There should be no interpolation. Your vertices should touch, but not connect across the seam. That way `uv.x` stops at `1.0` and it doesn't try to blend back down to `0.0`. [Try this texture](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg), to help visualize UVs. Here's how Three.js does it: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4503ef10b81a00f5c6c64fe9a856881ee31fe6a3/src/geometries/SphereGeometry.js#L43-L90